# Is there a partial sum formula for the Harmonic Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

There is a partial sum formula for $$\sum_{x=1}^n x^1 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and even one when the exponent of $x$ is $0$: $$\sum_{x=1}^n x^0 = n$$ but I cannot find one for exponent $-1$: $$\sum_{x=1}^n x^{-1} = ?$$

I tried $$\frac2{n(n+1)},$$ but that failed miserably.

Comment: Able to help on a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546174/322359 ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, there is no nice closed form for the [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). There are some very accurate approximations that are easily computed;

$$H_n\approx\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}$$

is quite good, where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Could you provide a source for that approximation please?

Comment: @zerosofthezeta: It’s at the link, at the bottom of the *Calculation* section of the article.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @zerosofthezeta: You’re welcome!

Comment: I've found a better approximation (for my purposes) using: `ln(x + 0.5) + 0.5772156649`

Comment: [This link in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) is giving a closed form for $H_n$! Am I right? But it looks much worse than the Harmonic series itself! :)

Comment: @H.R.: I wouldn't call either the integral representation or the alternating summation a closed form, but they do give alternative ways to look at $H_n$ that can be useful.

Comment: Interesting. I have to look into this. Why wouldnt a **finite** series have a closed form?

Comment: @Cogito, because a lot of times they really don't have one and thus you have to invent them. Consider e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$.

Comment: Saying they dont have one is contradictory to saying you have to invent one.  If one can be invented then it does in fact have one.

Comment: Anyone able to help answered a related question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546174/322359