# Overhang with dominos

Tags: calculus

I need to solve this problem

> By piling dominoes of 5 cm length, on the others at the edge of a table, we try to realize the biggest possible overhang. Dominoes like in balance under their own weight. 
>   For example with 1 domino we realize a 2.5 cm overhang. With 2 dominoes, we can realize a 3.75 cm overhang. 
>   How much dominoes is it necessary to realize an overhang of 1 m?

Is it a simple way to solve this equation without using a computer?

$$2.5\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right)=100\Leftrightarrow H_n=40$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not exactly. But [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series) furnishes a good approximation for the sum, which is a good starting place.

Comment: You probably do not realise it but there is a slight ambiguity in the question. From what you post you seem to be assuming that your dominoes are in a stack with only one domino on each level. But the way the question is worded that is not a requirement. For the more general case see [this paper](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~msp/papers/maximum_overhang.pdf).

Comment: I will read this paper, because the answer i find is false with my method. Thank you