# Prove this inequality: $\frac n2 \le \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac1{2^n - 1} \le n$

Tags: inequality, summation, harmonic-numbers

$\dfrac{n}{2} \le \dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{2^n - 1} \le n $

I've Tried for hours but didn't got any striking idea. I don't have any efforts to show rather than induction. Please Try If you 've non-inductive proof.

Comment: Hint:
$$
1 + \underbrace{\frac12 + \frac12} + \underbrace{\frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14 + \frac14} + \ldots
$$

Comment: Sorry couldn't get it.

Comment: Also, I think it helps to know that $2^n-1=1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @SolidSnake Yes, I know that But how it 'll help ?

Comment: I don't understand, 1/2, 1/4... does not fit in the sequence 1/(2^(n)-1)! Is the sequence correct or am I missing something

Comment: @martycohen: This question was posted on th 19th of July. The one that you reference was asked "9 hours ago". Which is the duplicate of which, then? I shall flag the other one and vote to leave this open.

Comment: I agree with @AlexM. .. my ques. is not duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Induction on $n$ really is the easiest way to go. Note that

$$\frac1{2^{n+1}-1}=\frac1{2^n+(2^n-1)}\;,$$

so there are $2^n$ terms in the expression

$$\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2^{n+1}-1}\;.$$

Now use the fact that each term is between $\dfrac1{2^{n+1}}$ and $\dfrac1{2^n}$.

For a non-inductive argument you could look at Riemann sums over subintervals of width $1$. If

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac1k\;,$$

show that

$$\int_1^{2^n}\frac{dx}x=n\ln 2\le S_n\le 1+\int_1^{2^n-1}\frac{dx}x=1+\ln(2^n-1)\;,$$

and use this to get the desired result. You’ll have to show that $1+\ln(2^n-1)\le n$ and that $n\ln 2\ge\dfrac{n}2$.

Comment: Good answer Brian, although I think O.P. wants a non-inductive proof.

Comment: @SolidSnake: Clearly the OP would prefer one, but experience says that other arguments may not be unwelcome. Also, including other arguments makes the question more valuable as a reference for users other than the OP. However, I’ve added a sketch of a non-inductive argument.

Comment: Great! I agree, your answer is perfectly fine and it adds a different argument that solves the problem. Thanks for the edit. (I was not the downvoter BTW).

Comment: It would be great answer, I accept it, but I don't know such higher mathematics, I'm a 11th grade student learning inequalities. I'm curious about different methods of problem solving, I'm not intelligent enough to find such methods, but I believe each idea has some meaning like idea about non--inductive proof. So, I've put my 'emotions' on this website. @BrianM.Scott given non-inductive proof but i can't get it. But does any elementary non-inductive proof exists ?

Comment: @user91374: I’ve been trying to think of one, but so far without any luck.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, so are you trying?Thanks.

Comment: @user91374: Actually, I’m about to go to bed. I’ll give it a little more thought, and I might get lucky, but at this point I honestly don’t expect to come up with anything.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : anyway, thanks for trying

Answer (score 4):

It's a standard trick. Let
$$
H_n = 1 + \frac12 +\ldots+ \frac1n.
$$
Look on $H_{2^n-1}$:
$$
n=1: H_1 = 1=1\\
n=2: H_3 = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 < 1 + \frac12 + \frac12 = 1 + 1=2\\
n=3: H_7 = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \left(\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17\right) < 1 + \frac{2}{2} + \left(\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14\right)=1 + 2 =3
$$
So, $H_{2^n-1} < n$. Analogously,
$$
n=1: H_1 = 1=1\\
n=2: H_3 = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 > 1 + \frac14 + \frac14 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\\
n=3: H_7 = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \left(\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17\right) > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18\right)=1 + \frac{2}{2},
$$
or in general
$$
H_{2^n-1}>1 + \frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}
$$

Comment: Note that this, if carried out rigorously, is also an induction argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I don't agreed. It *can* be prove by induction. But also you can note that $\frac1x > \frac{1}{2^n}$ if $x<2^n$; so, it's direct evaluation of lower bound for sum

Comment: I’m afraid not. If it’s written out in detail, it’s an induction argument. It’s just that the induction step is so obvious that it’s easy not to realize this.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, ok,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}-1}
$$
Is it induction? Even if so, it's "indirect" induction))

Comment: I agree with @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 1):

$H_m = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/m$

$\ln (m) < H_m < \ln (m + 1)$

put $m = 2^n - 1 $

$n/2 \leq \ln (2^n - 1)$

$\ln (2^n -1) + 1 \leq n $

Answer (score 1):

as a curiosity we may develop an approximation for the sum under consideration as a special case of a recondite formula cited by Brian Scott  [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series)

according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) 
$$
H_n = \ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2} + \frac1{120n^4} - \epsilon \tag{1}
$$
where $0 \lt \epsilon \lt \frac1{252n^6}$

for $n \gt 0$ we have:
$$
\log (2^n-1) = n \log 2 +\log (1 -2^{-n}) = n \log 2 - 2^{-n} - 2^{-(2n+1)} -R
$$
where $0 \lt R \lt 2^{-(3n+1)}$

also
$$
\frac1{2(2^n-1)} = 2^{-(n+1)}+ 2^{-(2n+1)} + R'
$$
where $0 \lt R' \lt 2^{-3n}$

and finally taking only the first term in the expansion of $\frac{2^{-2n}}{12(1-2^{-n})^2}$  we obtain the approximation:
$$
H_{2^n-1} \approx 0.69314718... n -\frac13(2^{-(n+1)}+\frac32)^2 + 1.32721566...
$$

btw, the wikipedia article cited is worth a browse - it contains some mind-boggling stuff! including this little gem:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \log^2 x dx = \gamma^2 + \frac{\pi^2}6
$$