# Find Big Oh for nested for loop with floor function

Tags: asymptotics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> sum $\gets 0$ 
>   for $i\gets 1$ to $n$ do 
>   $~~~~$ for $j \gets 1$ to $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{i}\right\rfloor$ do 
>   $~~~~~~~~~$ sum $\gets$ sum + ary$[i]$

I know $\sum_{i=1}^{n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so Im pretty sure I can just say $O(n^2)$ but Im not sure if this is the answer because perhaps its not precise enough. Im not sure how to incorporate the floor function. I also feel like the sum doesnt go to n it goes to $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{i}\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

Up to the rounding of the upper bound what you are looking for is the sum $n+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{3}+...+\frac{n}{n}$, which is $n$ times a partial sum of the harmonic series. You can find an approximation here, [Is there a partial sum formula for the Harmonic Series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series), and basically, your complexity will be $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: But would this answer still be consitent with there being a floor function?

Comment: Yes. The rounding subtracts at most one iteration from each of the inner loops, so the bound is $O(n\log n-n)=O(n\log n)$.

Comment: The formula Im looking at in my book for harmonic serires says for n>1 then ln n < Hn < ln n + 1. Why are using log instead of ln?

Comment: For complexity purposes all logarithms are equivalent.