# Can you help me with this sum?

Tags: summation

Why isn't there a proper solution on internet on this sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$$

Can you help me with your solution?

Comment: Simply put, no closed formula is known. Please see [Is there a partial sum formula for the Harmonic Series?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series&ved=2ahUKEwiUhPT5y4_hAhUImuAKHRlpA3gQFjAMegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0RKke9KdqHnrAxoCOlx1bm)

Comment: Look up [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The relation to the logarithm function is discussed in the answers to [Showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)=0.5772\ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344314/showing-that-lim-n-to-infty-sumn-k-1-frac1k-lnn-0-5772-ldots)

Comment: But isn't there a proper formula for every value of n considering that every "relative" of this equation has it?

Comment: What do you mean by "relative"?

Comment: I mean that there is a formula for every sum with alternation in the denominator from this one?

Comment: Not really.  If you sum the reciprocalds of all positive squares you get $\pi^2/6$, but what if you take only a finite number of terms?  The partial sum as a function of the numver of terms is a complicated thing that the simple expression for the limiting value, $\pi^2/6$, conceals.

Comment: But this sum looks really simple for finding its formula for solution with n in it.

Comment: Also, the sum to infinity of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ diverges; that is, it grows without bound, getting closer to $\log(n)+\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: I mean there should be a simple formula for finding every nth harmonic number right?

Comment: There are approximations that get pretty close. One is $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12k^2}+\frac1{120k^4}$$

Comment: If you can find a "simple" formula you will be famous among mathematicians.